# Something about command pattern, Why do most of the examples call receiver directly but not invoker in main?

Tags: design-patterns, command-pattern

Something about command pattern, Why do most of the examples call receiver directly but not invoker in client?

In most of the example on internet,(img : http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Diagrams/command.gif) ,why the client call the receiver to do action but not invoker? It seems like client call action via invoker or directly though command interface is better because the actual action coding is inside the receiver . If we change any path of action code, the changing on the code of receiver and client are necessary.
If we use invoker to call the actual command, it will reduce the dependency.

Therefore, why should we still call the action via receiver in general example? Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are reading a [class diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram) like it was a [sequence diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram). The sequence diagram for most common examples of [CommandPattern](http://javaobsession.wordpress.com/2010/07/25/command-pattern/) decribes how the client calls the action method through the Invoker as you expected.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I mean, call the actual command via invoker seems better, why dont they call the command via invoker but depend on receiver and concrete command?

Comment: With the pattern definition in mind: "Encapsulates a request allowing it to be treated as an object", the concrete Command class is the object that represents the request, therefore, the Client that is the one that makes the request needs to depend on it.
I agree that  the Client dependency with Receiver could be avoidable. Remeber that a design pattern is just a suggested solution for a problem, there are not only one possible implementation.